# How to implement server to server authentication in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication

Please provide me steps to implement server to server authentication in sharepoint.

Comment: Are you working on provider-hosted apps for SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

> Server-server authentication allows to access and request resources
>   from one server on behalf of users. Server –server authentication will
>   be possible in SharePoint 2013, Exchange Server 2013, Lync Server 2013
>   and others that support Microsoft server-server protocol.
>   Server-server authentication is separate from user authentication and
>   it is not used as sign-in authentication protocol. To plan
>   server-server authentication we have to identify the trust
>   relationship that to configure on the server runs on SharePoint 2013.
>   Trust relationship with another server that perform server-server
>   authentication consists, the server runs SharePoint2013 trusts the
>   request from server that can perform server-server authentication and
>   server that perform server-server authentication trusts request from
>   SharePoint 2013.

http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/241/Configure-server-server-authentication-in-SharePoint-2013
http://www.stickyglue.co.za/index.php/archives/191

Comment: Please mark the copy pasted text above as a quote (with the RTE tools available when you edit the post)! You must make it more clear that the text is just copy-pasted in here.

Comment: After configuring server to server authentication , how one web application will communicate with other? How to run that?